# mtd-utils error during yocto build

Tags: xilinx, yocto, bitbake, openembedded, petalinux

I'm trying to build `Petalinux` with `meta-swupdate` from https://github.com/Xilinx/yocto-manifests and https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate. I followed the directions for `Peatlinux` manifest. The command to build it was

```
TEMPLATECONF=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/sources/meta-petalinux/conf sources/core/oe-init-env-build petalinux-build-env
bitbake petalinux-image-full
```

Everything worked. Then I added a `meta-swupdate` layer to the `bblayers.conf` and rebuilt (`bitbake petalinux-image-full`). This is where the I'm having issues.

During the build I'm getting a following error:

```
| mkdir -p /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1
| install -m 0644 mkfs.jffs2.1 /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1/
| gzip -9f /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1/*.1
| install: cannot stat '/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git//include/libubi.h': No such file or directory
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/temp/log.do_install.385)
ERROR: Task (/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/sources/core/meta/recipes-devtools/mtd/mtd-utils_git.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5877 tasks of which 5875 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

I'm somewhat new to `Yocto` and not sure how to fix the problem. Would anyone care to help? The full log is attached

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
NOTE: make CC=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/sysroots/zynq-generic RANLIB=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ranlib AR=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-ar CFLAGS= -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0=/usr/src/debug/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/sysroots/zynq-generic=   -I/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git//include BUILDDIR=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ install DESTDIR=/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image SBINDIR=/usr/sbin MANDIR=/usr/share/man INCLUDEDIR=/usr/include  
mkdir -p /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/sbin
install -m 0755 /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ftl_format /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_erase /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/nanddump /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/doc_loadbios /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ftl_check /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/mkfs.jffs2 /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_lock /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_unlock /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_otp_info /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_otp_dump /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_otp_lock /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flash_otp_write /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/mtd_debug /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/flashcp /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/nandwrite /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/nandtest /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/mtdpart /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/jffs2dump /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/nftldump /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/nftl_format /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/docfdisk /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/rfddump /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/rfdformat /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/serve_image /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/recv_image /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/sumtool /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/jffs2reader /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/mkfs.ubifs/mkfs.ubifs /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubiupdatevol /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubimkvol /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubirmvol /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubicrc32 /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubinfo /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubiattach /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubidetach /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubinize /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubiformat /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubirename /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/mtdinfo /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubirsvol /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git/ubi-utils/ubiblock flash_eraseall /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/sbin/
mkdir -p /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1
install -m 0644 mkfs.jffs2.1 /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1/
gzip -9f /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/image//usr/share/man/man1/*.1
install: cannot stat '/home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/git//include/libubi.h': No such file or directory
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/someuser/projects/petalinux-build-system/petalinux-build-env/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/mtd-utils/1.5.2-r0/temp/log.do_install.385)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project appears to be using the Yocto 2.2 release code named morty. Use the [morty branch of meta-swupdate](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/tree/morty).

Comment: How did you know that it was using a `morty` branch? Do you mind pointing that out? Also which project were you talking about, `meta-petalinux` or `meta-swupdate`?

Comment: https://github.com/Xilinx/yocto-manifests/blob/rel-v2017.3/default.xml shows that they are using Xilinx's rel-v2017.3 poky branch. I then checked https://github.com/Xilinx/poky/commits/rel-v2017.3 and found that this is based on the upstream 2.2 poky release.